# Unable to Deploy EAR into websphere through jython script

Tags: websphere, jython

While am deploying ear through jython script to WebSphere application in Dev environment.I got the below error.

ERROR:

```
ADMA5017I: Uninstallation of appname started.
ADMA5104I: The server index entry for WebSphere:cell=dza1001Cell80,node=dza1001Node80 is updated successfully.
ADMA5102I: The configuration data for appname from the configuration repository is deleted successfully.
ADMA5011I: The cleanup of the temp directory for application appname is complete.
ADMA5106I: Application appname uninstalled successfully.
ADMA5016I: Installation of appname started.
ADMA5060E: Resource validation for application appname failed due to unexpected exception java.lang.NullPointerException
ADMA5011I: The cleanup of the temp directory for application appname is complete.
ADMA5069E: The installation of application appname failed.  This application was in the middle of a full update and therefore is uninstalled from the configuration session.  Discard your current configuration session immediately to recover the application.  Do not save changes to the WebSphere Application Server configuration repository.  The application is not uninstalled from this repository.  Until the current configuration session is discarded you do not see this application in the current session.
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "/data/scripts/deployAppQA.py"; exception information: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7418E: Application update for appname failed: see previous messages for details.

WASX7341W: No "save" was performed before the interactive scripting session exited; configuration changes will not be saved.
```

Error encountered while deploying the app

Comment: maybe do a save after the uninstall and before the install.